# Javascript Menu not Working Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I'm developing a horizontal menu with submenus. I need to use Javascript to show the submenu when the user hovers over the parent menu.

I wrote an example in JSFiddle, but it appears to fail in FireFox! In Chrome, IE and Safari is running!

Here's the test page:
[www.andreferreira.eu5.org](http://www.andreferreira.eu5.org)

Here's the code:
[jsfiddle.net/R2ySL/](http://jsfiddle.net/R2ySL/)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $nav = $('#menu > li');
    $nav.hover(
        function() {
            $('li', this).stop(true, true).slideDown('fast');

            $('a',this).first().css({"background-color":"#FFF", "color":"#debe65"});
        },
        function() {

            $('ul', this).slideUp('fast');
           $('a',this).first().css({"background-color":"", "color":"#FFF"});
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Works on FF 29.0.1.

Comment: Your first function is for `li` as `$('li', this)` but the second is for `ul` as `$('ul', this)` which i guess needs to be for `li` again.

Comment: You might want to move that script from out of the current location in the middle of the HTML to a separate JS file and link it in the usual way too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make that without changing css rules via javascript just add the following to your stylesheet

```
#menu li:hover > a {
    color: #debe65;
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

and javascript should looks like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $nav = $('#menu > li');
    $nav.hover(

    function () {
        $('li', this).stop(true, true).slideDown('fast');
    },

    function () {

        $('ul', this).slideUp('fast');
    });
});
```